# Направление зависимостей в приложении

Tags: c#, ооп, дизайн

Вопрос состоит в том какие модули от чего зависят?
Хочу разобрать на примере веб приложения (серверная часть). Используемая технология asp.net Web api 2.0 или asp.net MVC.
В проекте имеются сборки содержащие бизнес логику (Core/Services), доступ к данным (DAL), построение отчетов(Reports), само веб-приложение содержащее контроллеры куда приходят запросы (API) + сборка с вьюмоделью (ViewModel).

Как было бы правильно организовать зависимости между этими модулями ? Я себе представляю примерно так:

В (Core/Services) находится самая важная и сложная часть программы, по-этому она не должна зависеть от кого-то еще. Она определяет протокол работы с данными (возможно в виде интерфейсов которые должны реализовать классы из DAL и принимает их в конструкторы) соответственно DAL знает только о Core/Services и реализует то что она просит.

В API приходит запрос и на этом уровне определяется валидность данных в запросе и формирование ответа. API обращается к ViewModel за данными которые будут отправлены клиенту для отображения либо к Reports для формирования отчетов. ViewModel в свою очередь запрашивает данные из Core/Services либо требует что бы пришедшие с клиента данные каким-то образом были обработаны (сохранены/обновлены и.т.д.).

Верно ли так организовывать зависимости между модулями ? Какие проблемы могут у меня возникнуть при таком раскладе ?